# String Extra not passing to new Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to pass a String extra to an activity via an Intent. I'm passing a boolean and a String. The boolean passes just fine, and I've confirmed it in my logcat by printing it out. However the String keeps coming through as null.

Here is the code where I pass the intent in my TopicsActivity.java:

```
private class TopicsListListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    /*
     * Fields for the keys and topic tree map
     */
    private final String[] keys;
    private final Map topicTree;

    /*
     * Constructor accepts key array and topic tree map and assigns them to respective fields
     */
    TopicsListListener(String[] keys, Map topicTree) {
        super();
        this.topicTree = topicTree;
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    /*
     * Passes an Intent to the Public Messages List activity containing the t-[id] of the
     * selected topic and an isPrivate value of false (Public)
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent topicMessages = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MessagesActivity.class);
        String TID = (String) topicTree.get(keys[position]);
        Log.d("TID", TID);
        Bundle intentBundle = new Bundle();
        intentBundle.putBoolean("isPrivate", isPrivate);
        intentBundle.putString("tid", TID);
        topicMessages.putExtra("bundle", intentBundle);
        startActivity(topicMessages);

    }
}
```

And here is my code where I am trying to retrieve the String:

```
/*
 * Fields for the Activity
 */
private ListView topicsList;
public boolean isPrivate;

/*
 * Fields used for Intents
 */
private String TID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_topics);

    /*
     * Get the status of isPrivate from the Dashboard activity
     */
    Intent topics = getIntent();
    Bundle intentInfo = topics.getBundleExtra("bundle");
    isPrivate = intentInfo.getBoolean("isPrivate");
    Log.d("TOPICS isPrivate", "" + isPrivate);
    TID = intentInfo.getString("tid");

    TextView temp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tempText);
    temp.setText(TID);
```

The temp.setText(TID); line is throwing a NullPointerException. Here is a piece of my logcat when this happens:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.topicplaces.android.MessagesActivity.onCreate(MessagesActivity.java:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
```

Here is the `TextView` from xml:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/tempText" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp"      
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:text="Hello World" 
     android:layout_above="@+id/newMessageButton" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

If it matters, the TopicsActivity.java is also started via an Intent from another activity called Dashboard.java. Any help here is appreciated, I've been scratching my head all day on this. I think I have read every Intent related post here on StackOverflow and haven't found any explanation regarding this.

Comment: Can you do Log.d on the string retrieved to see if it is null? From the logcat it seems to me that it is your textview (temp) that's returning null, not the string

Comment: I did a Log.d on the TID on the String and was getting a NullPointerException on that as well.

The Log.d of the TID in my click listener before startActivity() displays the proper String.

Comment: as @JoelMin says, your TextView (R.id.tempText) might be null. It doesn't look like your String can be null, to make sure you are passing the data into the Bundle you can log the Bundle using toString()

Comment: make sure `activity_topics` layout file has a textview with id..`tempText`

Comment: may be it is in another layout.. and your accessing another one

Comment: I tossed a Log.d on the Bundle before passing it putExtra() and this is what I got:

09-14 20:38:53.196  26344-26344/com.topicplaces.android D/BUNDLE﹕ Bundle[{isPrivate=true, tid=grp-2kua91kbvcmfwfsczv9}]

So the TID String is successfully being added to the Bundle.

Comment: activity_topics has a layout for the TextView with the id of tempText or else my findViewById() would be errored out in my code. Here is the XML from activity_topics:

<TextView android:id="@+id/tempText"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textSize="20sp"
                      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:text="Hello World"
                      android:layout_above="@+id/newMessageButton"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
private class TopicsListListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    /*
     * Fields for the keys and topic tree map
     */
    private final String[] keys;
    private final Map topicTree;
    private Context mContext;

    /*
     * Constructor accepts key array and topic tree map and assigns them to respective fields
     */
    TopicsListListener(Context context, String[] keys, Map topicTree) {
        super();
        this.topicTree = topicTree;
        this.keys = keys;
        mContext = context;
    }

    /*
     * Passes an Intent to the Public Messages List activity containing the t-[id] of the
     * selected topic and an isPrivate value of false (Public)
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent topicMessages = new Intent(mContext, MessagesActivity.class);
        String TID = (String) topicTree.get(keys[position]);
        topicMessages.putExtra("TID", TID);
        topicMessages.putExtra("isPrivate", isPrivate);
        mContext.startActivity(topicMessages);    
    }
}
```

It should solve your issue.

Comment: This got it working for the most part (I had to make a few minor changes). Odd, I used this exact same code earlier today and was getting the NullPointException then. That is why I switched to the Bundle. I must have missed something earlier today.

Thank you!

Comment: @Jeff Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

By some reason it's your **TextView** equals to null, not **TID** String
You **can** use setText(null) on any **TextView** and it wouldn't crash your app, just would clear the text
Are you sure you have a **TextView** with **tempText** id attribute in your activity `activity_topics.xml` layout?

```
android:id="@+id/tempText"
```

Comment: Here is the XML for the TextView:

<TextView android:id="@+id/tempText"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:textSize="20sp"
                      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:text="Hello World"
                      android:layout_above="@+id/newMessageButton"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

So the TextView shouldn't be null here.

Comment: @Jeff: please update XML code into your question. Are you sure `tempText` is in `activity_topics` layout?

Comment: And where is this code located? Show your `activity_topics.xml` layout code. The TextView must be there

Answer (score 0):

Try, change:

```
topicMessages.putExtra("bundle", intentBundle);
Bundle intentInfo = topics.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

To:

```
topicMessages.putExtra(intentBundle);
Bundle intentInfo = topics.getExtra();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code where you receiving the bundle like:

```
Bundle intentInfo = topics.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

and

```
topicMessages.putExtra("bundle", intentBundle);
```

to

```
Bundle intentInfo = topics.getExtras("bundle");
```

and

```
topicMessages.putExtras("bundle", intentBundle);
```

i think you are not getting the value of boolean also, may be you are chacking 
false, it is the default value of boolean variable.